# How to populate an attribute from other attributes

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

To my sign up screen, I added 2 built-in fields: First Name and Last Name. In the Users | All users
list, a new user appears with the Name of "unknown". That is because I did not add the "Display Name" attribute. I don't want to make the user fill this additional field. Is it possible to set the Display Name to be populated on the back end as First Name + " " + Last Name?

Comment: Are you using Custom Policies (Identity Experience Framework), or User Flows?

Comment: @BradC. User Flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your two options are:

1. Enable Custom HTML/JavaScript for your User Interface that will effectively hide the `Display Name` field, and combine the `First Name` and `Last Name`, respectively.
2. Use the more complex, but powerful Identity Experience Framework and leverage a `ClaimsTransformation`:

Example:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="Generate-DisplayName" TransformationMethod="FormatStringMultipleClaims">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenname" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1"/>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2"/>
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0} {1}"/>
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried this solution for hours but it doesn't appear that the displayName is being saved correctly. Is there anything else that needs to be done? We have a custom user journey that calls an API. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @AnupMarwadi - Which of the two solutions listed above are you having trouble with? We'd need to see the Custom Policy XML in order to tell you if it was impacting the persistence of your displayName attribute.

Comment: I will add a gist soon!

Comment: Hello Brad C. here is the gist. Important to note that we have custom user journeys. I have also tried to override the AAD policies with multiple different combinations but none seem to work. Any help would be highly appreciated. Added enough comments on the most important XML nodes. https://gist.github.com/hypertrends/18b7743c873a189699d19624f5a97be1

Comment: @AnupMarwadi - Here's a gist that I put together quickly that demonstrates the very basics. It's a self-asserted page that collects the first and last names, respectively and then uses a `ClaimsTransformation` technical profile to create the display name. You should be able to change the tenant information in the header and run it yourself.

https://gist.github.com/BradCandell/35aa6fc365bcb2127f0c8e2c6eefa516